# Import CocoaPods (Swift) to Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I would like to use a Cocoa Podfile called **SwiftCSV**, as I understand it is already written in Swift.

I would now like to import this in my class but I cannot figure out how I have to do it.
Can anyone relate to that?

This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SwiftCSV'
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem. I futzed around with the helper files and so on until I found that `pod install` did not install the frameworks correctly. I added the framework manually, then it worked.

So do the Podfile, `pod install`, use the ".xcworkspace" project - this is CocoaPods 101 - and then the steps below

My Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
pod "SwiftCSV"
```

1 - Make sure the framework is linked in the project/target.

- Click on the project -> Target -> General -> Linked Frameworks and
  Libraries and hit "+"
- Add the SwiftCSV.framework. Pods.framework was already added for me, so I guess pod install did that part correctly.

2 - In the swift file that wants to use SwiftCSV:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftCSV  // <===== I had to add this

class SomeClassThatUsesSwiftCSV {
  var foo: CSV?
}
```

For verification, make sure your project "Frameworks" group looks like this:
[image]

Note: I am new to CocoaPods but I would expect that `pod install` does all this for me. That's the whole point of it, isn't it? But, it didn't, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to know how is the line you have to put to import a library using Cocoapods I strongly recommend you go to https://cocoapods.org/ an put the name of the package you want and then you will see the line you need to put in your `pod` file if the package is available for Cocoapods of course.

For your package https://cocoapods.org/?q=SwiftCSV you have to put the following line :

```
pod 'SwiftCSV', '~> 0.1'
```

When starting out with a project it is likely that you will want to use the latest version of a Pod. If this is the case, simply omit the version requirements as you do it in you above pod.

You can read more about it the Podfile in the [Cocoapods guides](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

Then you have go to the directory where your `pod` file is and run in the console `pod install`.

And to use the library you want just put  `import SwiftCSV` wherever you want to use it.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you! My question is more about how I can call the classes of my Pods in xcode. There is a little tutorial for SwiftCSV and I tried it, but it gives me an error, because it cannot find the class (in my case called CSV). After i run "pod install" don't I have to import anything into my xcode Project?

Comment: I just update my pod with you package and put `import SwiftCSV` and works fine!!!

Comment: ok.. so there is hope! thank you! I delete everything and try it again.